# Why can't my Xamarin Forms application see my database table?

Tags: c#, database, azure, xamarin

I am new to mobile development and I'm having trouble with my Xamarin Forms application.  I have an Azure subscription in place with a mobile app setup with a connection to my database.  I have downloaded the two quickstart projects from Mobile App Quickstart link in Azure and reconfigured them to look for a table called "users" within my database and return data from it.

When I run the app from Visual Studio which is using a MacBook pro as a simulator the list comes back as blank.  I put a couple of break points in place and I can see that it's stating the resource cannot be found.

When it looks for the table to return a collection it hits the catch in the method like so:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<users>> GetUserItemsAsync(bool syncItems = false)
        {
            try
            {
#if OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED
                if (syncItems)
                {
                    await this.SyncAsync();
                }
#endif
                IEnumerable<users> items = await userTable.ToEnumerableAsync();

                return new ObservableCollection<users>(items);
            }
            //Hits this catch
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message, msioe.StackTrace, msioe.Request, msioe.Response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The error returned is as follows:

```
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
```

I added a response and request to the catch statement to try and see exactly what the problems was.  The request returned the following:

```
{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://myurl.azurewebsites.net/tables/users', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
X-ZUMO-FEATURES: TT
X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: r8fv3f71-12e9-416f-a976-8are363cf3b7
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: ZUMO/3.1 (lang=Managed; os=iOS; os_version=10.2; arch=MacOSX; version=3.1.50105.0)
X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/3.1 (lang=Managed; os=iOS; os_version=10.2; arch=MacOSX; version=3.1.50105.0)
ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
}}
```

I can see it thinks that either the table isn't there or it's empty.  I created the table and populated it with dummy data so I know it's there.

Perhaps my process was wrong though, I crated the table from Visual Studio which was connected to my azure subscription.  Do tables need to be set up a certain way? am I supposed to use Easy Tables from within Azure?

I need some guidance here in understanding why my app cannot see my database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to having a database: Have you set up a Web API (or Azure Mobile App) with either **Easy Tables** or a custom Web API project with [Azure Mobile Tables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables/) ?

This is required for the Mobile Client Tables to work.

A quick tutorial for getting started with Easy Tables is [there](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/).

A starting point for creating a custom Mobile App backend can be found there (https:// learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk)

Comment: I have the Mobile App setup in Azure @woelliJ however I didn't create my table using Easy Tables, I used the SQL Object Browser.  Sadly trying to install Microsoft.Azure.Server.Mobile.Tables or even Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.2.0.0 throw up errors from Nuget stating that the target framework is no good for these items.  I did try to change it but it said it couldn't.  I've been groing around in circles trying to install these items.

Comment: Database tables are not directly exposed by creating them. The Microsoft.Azure.Server.Mobile.Tables package is for the server project. You need to expose your database via some kind of webservice (using Microsoft.Azure.Server.Mobile.Tables) or via ´Easy Tabes´.

Comment: Ahh right yes, that is what you get from the sample projects in Azure @woelliJ .  So that element already exists.  I did a little more digging and found this article http://www.strathweb.com/2012/12/using-existing-database-with-azure-mobile-services/ which shows that you still need to create the tables using EasyTables even if they exist.  I've managed to do that and my application no longer gets stuckk at the catch.  My next problem is that despite this process I can't return any data, I used Postman to test the rest statement but it returns nothing.

Comment: I think you're confusing Easy Tables with a Web API which is using the OData Tables Access (back in 2012 - the time of that blog entry - easy tables hasn't existed yet). I think we need to clear some things up: 1. Have you hosted a server ASP.NET application on Azure to access the database? 2. Have you configured Easy Tables as described in https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/ ?

If none of that: you can't access the database via the Mobile App Tables API and you have to set up either of the mentioned solutions

Comment: Ok right, my apologise please bear with me :D trying to get my head around this.  1: Yes I have, I downloaded the quickstart project which ASP.NET application for accessing the database and I uploaded that project to the Mobile App directory site/wwwroot/ 2: Not exactly as that aricle describes no, I will attempt that approach however. Thanks for all the help so far @woelliJ it's been a massive help.